# python subprocess set shell var. and then run command - how?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to do this:

```
$ export PYRO_HMAC_KEY=123
$ python -m Pyro4.naming
```

So, i found that the second one is possible to do with

```
subprocess.Popen(['python','-m','Pyro4.naming'])
```

but how export shell variable before that?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to switch from shell to Python? If the shell script works, it can easily be called from Python.

Comment: yes, I dont want to create additional file like `run_me.sh` it is not so... canonical way:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To update the existing environment...

```
import os, subprocess

d = dict(os.environ)   # Make a copy of the current environment
d['PYRO_HMAC_KEY'] = '123'
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'Pyro4.naming'], env=d)
```

Comment: or as a one-liner: `env=dict(os.environ, PYRO_HMAC_KEY='123')`

Comment: The env setting could be used with `subprocess.check_output()` and `subprocess.run()`, too.

Answer (score 9):

The subprocess functions accept an `env` argument that can be given a mapping of environment variables to use in the process:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python','-m','Pyro4.naming'], env={'PYRO_HMAC_KEY': '123'})
```

Comment: This leaves the subprocess's environment empty except for 'PYRO_HMAC_KEY'.

Answer (score 0):

Try os.putenv(): http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.putenv